# How to use react routing when the text which is to be clicked is rendering with its own component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am really stuck at this as I am not getting any possible solution for this.
I want to navigate to  Profile section when '/profile' is in the url on click on the sidebar options but I am not able to work with  in the sidebaroptions as they are created by passsing props in Sidebarjs.

Any possible solution on how to deal with the routing when the links are created dnyamically thourgh components.

Sidebar.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import './Sidebar.css';
import SidebarOption from './SidebarOption';
import AccountCircleIcon from '@material-ui/icons/AccountCircle';
import FolderSpecialIcon from '@material-ui/icons/FolderSpecial';
import BusinessIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Business';

function Sidebar() {
    return (
        <div className="sidebar">
            <SidebarOption title="Projects" Icon={FolderSpecialIcon}/>
            <SidebarOption title="Experience" Icon={BusinessIcon}/>
            <SidebarOption title="Profile" Icon={AccountCircleIcon}/>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Sidebar;
```

SidebarOptions.js

```
import React from 'react';
import './SidebarOption.css';
import { Link, BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

function SidebarOption({title, Icon}) {
    return (
        <div className="sidebarOption">
            {Icon && <Icon fontSize="large" className="sidebarOption__Icon" />}
            {Icon && Icon ? <h4>{title}</h4> : <p>{title}</p>}
        </div>
    )
}

export default SidebarOption
```

Body.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import './Body.css';
import Profile from "./Profile";
import Projects from "./Projects";


function Body() {
    return (
        <Router>
            <div className="body">
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path="/" component={Profile}>

                    </Route>
                    <Route path="/projects" component={Projects}>

                    </Route>
                    <Route path="/experience">
                        <h5>This is Experience.</h5>
                    </Route>
                </Switch>
            </div>
        </Router>
    )
}

export default Body;
```

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Navbar from './Navbar';
import Sidebar from './Sidebar';
import Body from './Body';

function App() {
  return (
      <div className="app">
        <Sidebar />
        <Body />
      </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: If you are trying to navigate from SideBar Component then you've to initialize SideBar within Router tag to access it's navigation props liike props.history.push('Profile')

Comment: `Sidebar` needs to be rendered within a `Router`, any usages outside and error messages likely would have informed you of this requirement.

Comment: I see you are importing {Link} but don't see any place in your code you are actually using the <Link> component. That of course will be needed to wire up the routing.

Comment: @ZuhairNaqi I am creating Sidebar separately as I am rendering the body only on routing. SIdebar is not part of the body.

Comment: @DrewReese I was getting an error that i can't use LInk outside Router so what i did in SIdebar.js, I wrapped individual SidebarOption and wrapped all of that again inside BrowserRouter that way the routing url is getting changed but the component isn't re-rendering.

Comment: @Anthos Can you update your question with your current code (what you say is wrapped with a router), and if possible, provide a minimal running example in a reproducible codesandbox that can be live debugged?